# Graduate schools that do not require letters of recommendation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am applying for PhD in Mathematics. I have been surfing the internet to find grad schools that do not require letters of recommendation. Can anyone help me with suggestions on some schools I could look out for?

Comment: You will probably obtain better results if you ask this at academia stackexchange

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you been self-teaching? If so, the best thing to do is develop a relationship with a professor somewhere, if possible.

Comment: No PhD program worth doing would admit you without such recommendations!